# Decent, simple audio interface / external soundcard?

Tags: audio, audio-adapters

I'm currently during the week at one place (A) and during the weekend at another (B) and have to take my soundcard with me so I can use my surround system + headset at place A and my headset at place B. Now I've decided to look into getting a secondary sound card / audio interface for place B and am asking for recommendations here.

Mandatory requirements:

- Must feature at least one 6.3mm / 3.5mm audio jack input
- Must feature at least one 6.3mm / 3.5mm audio jack headphone output
- Must use USB for power-supply and data connection to the computer
- Must suppport Windows (10)
- Must feature decent quality of the involved audio components
- Must be able to feed 80 Ohm headphones
- Must feature at least 48kHz / 16 bit sampling
- Must stay below 100€ in price, there's no problem at all if the price is around 50€

Optional requirements:

- May feature excellent quality of the involved audio components
- Should feature a 192kHz / 24 bit sampling rate
- Should be as cheap as possible, but may trade better quality / sampling rates against a higher price

Answer (score 1):

The focusrite 2i2 has what you need. [Here is a link](http://www.adorama.com/frsc2i2usb.html?gclid=CjwKEAiA7ejCBRDlp8uF6ezPnjoSJAAPED7MHtXexM6vqmXUx4mDSLmBXI6ZzZlYhPaYXwKV7q51RxoCy1bw_wcB) that has the full specs, but some of the relevant ones are:

> Front panel
>
> - 2x line/mic/instrument combination inputs high quality XLR / 1/4" TRS Jack
> - Combo 2x Line/Instrument switches
> - 2x Gain knobs
> - 2x Gain halo signal indicators 48V Phantom power switch Direct monitor switch
> - Large monitor level dial
> - USB Connection LED indicator
> - Headphone output - 1/4" TRS Jack
> - Headphone level knob
>
> Rear panel
>
> - 2 balanced monitor outputs 1/4" TRS Jack
> - USB 2.0 Port
> - Kensington Lock slot
>
> Digital Performance: Supported rates 44.1 KHz, 48 KHz, 88.2 KHz, 96 KHz
>
> Dimensions (H x W x D) 45 x 175 x 100mm / 1.77 x 6.88 x 3.93"
>
> Weight 580g / 20.45oz

I regret not saving up for the 2i4, so you may want to consider that. But overall, I have been very happy with my 2i2, plus I must say, their customer service is excellent. Hope this helps!

Comment: I regret not saving for 4 inputs either. If you know there is a chance you'll need them, save now, and get it now. It'll be cheaper in the long run and when the 3rd and 4th mics become necessary, you'll be happy you spent that extra money.